# How to call a function with the same name within another class?

Tags: c++, function, class

I have two classes, a Card class and Deck class. Both have display() functions, and I cannot change the name of the function. I am unsure of how I can call Card::display() inside of Deck::display().

**Card.cpp**

```
void Card::display( ) const
{
   cout << rank << suit;
}
```

**Deck.cpp** //in Deck.h I did #include "Card.h", I did not have Deck inherit
because Deck did not need to access the private member variables of Card (aka suit and rank)

```
void Deck::display( ) const 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) 
    {
       if (i % 13 == 0 && i != 0)
       {
          cout << "\n";
          deck[i].display(); <--//deck is an array of 52 Cards, each index consists of
                            // a rank and a suit; here I am trying
                            //to display the entire deck of cards 4 by 13 2d array
                            //hence why I want to call the display function from class
                            // Card
       }
       else
       {
        deck[i].display() <--
       }
    }
}
```

So that when the display function from Deck is called from the main.cpp
it will look like (for example, if the cards are in order):

```
AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S ... (all the way until King of Spades) KS //new line, new row
AH ...(all the way until King of Hearts) KH  //new line, next row    
AD ...(all the way until King of Diamonds) KD   //new line, next row 
AC ...(all the way until King of Clubs) KC
```

Because the Card::display function (from code snippet above) displays
the rank then suit, and Deck::display would display the entire deck of cards.
I have been trying to do my own research online to no avail, so I would appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: Have you actually tried to compile and run the code?  I don't see a problem here.  If you have a problem, you need to post enough code to reproduce it.

Comment: Yes, what is the problem exactly? Given the description the code looks fine.

Comment: BTW your reasoning about, and expectations of, inheritance are completely wrong. But the decision not to have Deck inherit from Card is correct, just not for the reasons you state.

Comment: I did run the output, but I got an error hence why I thought it had to do with the function name. I appreciate the help thanks! @John Can you explain the inheritance bit to me? I want clarification

Comment: @Jasmine Use inheritance to model 'is a' relationships. A dog is an animal, so class Dog inherits from class Animal. Obviously a deck is not a card, instead a deck is composed of many cards. Inheritance is not the right way to model the relationship between a deck and a card. Instead you should make a Deck class contain an array of Card objects (which it seems you have done).

Comment: @Jasmine And in any case, on a technical point, inheritance would not get one class access to another classes private member variables. Friendship is the way to do that.

Comment: @John Thanks for the clarification, I forgot that friend functions are used to access private members and got confused with inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If deck is an array of Cards(as you mentioned), than when you write:

```
deck[i].display()
```

This display function will be implicit the display function of your Card class, so your code should be fine